# Flex mx:DataGrid | mx:appliaction | search cell

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I have checkboxes that are used to filter a dataGrid color column. I'm trying to return a color, however the data has many variations. Here's an example of the for the piece of code that I'm using

```
var whiteColor:Boolean =WhiteCheckBox.selected ? item.FACE_COLOR == "White" : false;
```

to return products that are available in white. This works however the cells include "White", "white,Black", "White,Bisque,Black", etc. Is the a way to the find a match for the cells that include "white" so I don't have to go this route:

```
var whiteColor:Boolean =WhiteCheckBox.selected ? item.FACE_COLOR == "White" || item.FACE_COLOR =="White,Bisque,Black" || item.FACE_COLOR =="White,Biscuit,Black" || item.FACE_COLOR =="White,Black" : false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
var reg:String = "ig";
var wht:RegExp = new RegExp("White", reg);  
var wht_match:Boolean = wht.test(item.FACE_COLOR);
var whiteColor:Boolean =White.selected ? wht_match : false;
```